# How to find the R version under which an R package was built?

Tags: r, search, package, version

**Root of problem:**
My environment is RevoREnt 7.3 that is tied with R 3.1.1.
I need to install `tidyr` package. `tidyr` needs `DBI` package.
I installed/loaded DBI (v0.5). R gave warning:

```
Warning message:
package ‘DBI’ (0.5) was built under R version 3.3.1
```

After installing/loading DBI (v0.5), my search help function was corrupted with error: i.e.,
"`?? yay`"in R console gave the following error:

```
"Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , "name", value = sub("\\.[^.]*$", "", basename(vDB$File))) : subscript out of bounds"
```

Then, instead of Uninstall/Reinstall RevoREnt, I decided to save my broken RevoREnt (noticing that there are many R user facing corrupted search help function without any solution to mend).

I unload/uninstall DBI from R console, then I deleted the folder of DBI package from R library location via Windows Explorer. I re-run RevoREnt and write "??yay" in console: 
My Help Browser (http://127.0.0.1:27971/doc/html/Search?pattern=yay) was opened
"The search string was "yay". No results found." appeared there.
That is: I saved my search help function without uninstalling/Re-installing RevoREnt.

**What I did to solve/find:**
**1.** Since I very needeed tidyr package, I decided to install/load DBI package that is compatible with my R 3.1.1. I went CRAN DBI (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/index.html)

There, it writes "`Depends: R (≥ 2.15.0)`" in DBI page.

Does this mean that DBI (v0.5) was built under R2.15.0?

**2.** I went to DBI's archieve: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DBI/

Tried to find one by one loading and checking the warnings in R console:

```
Warning message:
package ‘DBI’ (0.5) was built under R version 3.3.1 
Warning message:
package ‘DBI’ (0.4) was built under R version 3.1.3
Warning message:
package ‘DBI’ (0.3.1) was built under R version 3.1.2
```

Eventually, by trial and error, I found DBI 0.3.1 does not corrupt my search help function though it is built under 3.1.2>3.1.1!

Then, I reversed back. This time DBI 0.4 also did not corrupt search help function unexpectedly.  DBI 0.5 always continued to corrupt the search help function.

*Isn't there any simple way of finding R version under which the packages were built?*

Comment: Did you only try your tests with unloading & uninstalling vs shutting down all R sessions, starting R vanilla and doing the remove/reinstall?

Comment: When I do tests, I unloaded & uninstalled `DBI` package, then I completely shut down RevoREnt. Restarted RevoREnt, and then tried a new version of `DBI`. Hence, I did the tests under fresh R vanilla sessions. Inconsistency  for `DBI v0.4` is very interesting. Also, though both 3.1.2 and 3.3.1 bigger than 3.1.1, why `DBI v0.5` corrupts whereas `DBI v0.3.1` does not corrupt is also interesting. I could not solve the reasons for these 2 things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you want is in the last column ("Built") of the output of `installed.packages()`, per https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/installed.packages.html.

```
.libPaths() # get the library location
installed.packages(lib.loc = "C://Revolution//R-Enterprise-7.3//R-3.1.1//library")
```